# Why can I not create a wheel in python?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

Here are the commands I am running:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)

$ python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)"
2.1

$ python --version
Python 3.4.1

$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Also, I am running a mac with homebrewed python

Here is my setup.py script:
https://gist.github.com/cloudformdesign/4791c46fe7cd52eb61cd

I'm going absolutely crazy -- I can't figure out why this wouldn't be working.

Comment: And you have installed the `wheel` package as Thomas' answer advises?

Comment: I have the same problem.
But it seems that i didn't use sudo before the commend. After use the commend with administrate permission. it worked.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Install the [`wheel` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) first:

```
pip install wheel
```

The documentation isn't overly clear on this, but *"the wheel project provides a bdist_wheel command for setuptools"* actually means *"the wheel **package**..."*.

Comment: So that spit out the file: nioblocks-1.01-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl  -- will this work with any OS, or is there something else I have to do to get it to work?  (the "package" is just a bunch of dependencies for pip to install right now)

Comment: @GarrettLinux I wouldn't know, I'm sorry, but I'd encourage you to ask a separate question for that ; )

Comment: I fixed that problem too -- adding any file to the setup.py file gave it a general wheel. Check out the updated code in my question for example.

Comment: You can get the OP's error even with wheel installed, if the setup.py somehow uses distutils instead of setuptools (as was case for me), see the answer by geographika.

Comment: For me the problem was old version of pip.  fixed by `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: One may also need `sudo pip install wheel` if encountering permission problems.

Comment: @CodePlumber my favorite is `pip install wheel --user` for installing "globally".

Comment: I was having the same issue, and `pip install wheel` didn't do anything, but `conda install wheel` solved it.

Answer (score 170):

I also ran into the error message `invalid command 'bdist_wheel'`

It turns out the package setup.py used distutils rather than setuptools. 
Changing it as follows enabled me to build the wheel.

```
#from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import setup
```

Comment: yup, I had that problem at one time as well! Very important, and the error message is poor.

Comment: @geographika yes this is command also the documentation on https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html would replicate the issues you are seeig as it uses disutils

Comment: May also be necessary to change `from distutils.core import Extension, Command` to `from setuptools import Extension, Command` at least for package I was working with.

Comment: I got this error for pycrypto and it wasn't even importing setup. However, I added `from setuptools import setup` at the beginning and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 39):

Update your setuptools, too.

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

If that fails too, you could try with additional `--force` flag.

Comment: my setuptools was removed, or something was wrong.  So I had to do : pip install setuptools --upgrade --force

Answer (score 14):

I also ran into this all of a sudden, after it had previously worked, and it was because I was inside a virtualenv, and `wheel` wasn’t installed in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 11):

Update your `pip` first:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

for Python 3:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This is the most useful answer now. Newer versions of pip install don't use bdist_wheel, so just upgrading pip worked for me, without needing to install/update setuptools or wheel

Answer (score 5):

Throwing in another answer: Try checking your `PYTHONPATH`.

First, try to install `wheel` again:

```
pip install wheel
```

This should tell you where wheel is installed, eg:

```
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

Then add the location of wheel to your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wheel
```

Now building a wheel should work fine.

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Answer (score 4):

It could also be that you have a python3 system only. 
You therefore have installed the necessary packages via pip3 install , like *pip3 install wheel*.

You'll need to build your stuff using python3 specifically.

```
python3 setup.py sdist
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything said here without any luck, but found a workaround.
After running this command (and failing) : `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`

Go to the temporary directory the tool made (given in the output of the last command), then execute `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. The `.whl` file is in the `dist` folder.