# Django: error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

Tags: python, django

I have installed the packages but met the `traceback`,which shows `error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'`.

I referenced [Why can I not create a wheel in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664102/why-can-i-not-create-a-wheel-in-python)

wheel ,setuptools --force, --upgrade pip was all updated and installed.

So I am confused why it still error.

```
[192.168.15.xxx] out:   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for bokeh ... [?25lerror

[192.168.15.xxx] out:   Complete output from command /home/user/project/weather_station/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-25c2v483/bokeh/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpn5f73qcnpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:

[192.168.15.xxx] out:

[192.168.15.xxx] out:

[192.168.15.xxx] out:   usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

[192.168.15.xxx] out:      or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

[192.168.15.xxx] out:      or: -c --help-commands

[192.168.15.xxx] out:      or: -c cmd --help

[192.168.15.xxx] out:

[192.168.15.] out:   error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
```

Comment: any soloution for this error???

Comment: Have you installed `wheel`?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, make sure your import in setupy.py is correct:

```
from setuptools import setup
```

I had the same error with a setup.py created automatically by pycharm which created to following **WRONG** import statement:

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

So make sure your are importing the correct `setup` module.