# How to install pyautogui?

Tags: pip, installation, pyautogui

Hi i'm currently tring to install pyautogui with pip but i get this error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\elève\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\elève\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\ELVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7dknhnd'
     cwd: C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kccgkr83\pymsgbox
Complete output (14 lines):
running dist_info
creating C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-10ci4w8d\PyMsgBox.egg-info
writing C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-10ci4w8d\PyMsgBox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-10ci4w8d\PyMsgBox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-10ci4w8d\PyMsgBox.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-10ci4w8d\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-10ci4w8d\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 0: unexpected end of data (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'pymsgbox'
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-10ci4w8d\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating 'C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-10ci4w8d\PyMsgBox.dist-info'
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\elève\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\elève\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\ELVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7dknhnd' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried to update pip already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I not create a wheel in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664102/why-can-i-not-create-a-wheel-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+invalid+command+bdist_wheel

Answer (score 1):

You can install PyAutoGui using either:
`pip install pyautogui`

OR by running the code given below in PyCharm/Shell

```
from subprocess import *
from sys import *

call([executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "pyautogui"])
```