# TA-Lib install - Debian - venv - pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, virtualenv

New to python, problems installing TA-Lib.  Using pycharm on a virtual environment located on external mounted hd

---

- `Linux debian 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `~/lib/ta-lib/ta-lib# python3`

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
```

- `/lib/ta-lib/ta-lib# pip3 install TA-Lib`

```
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/cf/681911aa31e04ba171ab4d523a412f4a746e30d3eacb1738799d181e028b/TA-Lib-0.4.19.tar.gz (267kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 169kB/s
Collecting numpy (from TA-Lib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/e1/8c4c5632adaffc18dba4e03e97458dc1cb00583811e6982fc620b9d88515/numpy-1.19.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.4MB 117kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: TA-Lib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for TA-Lib ... error
  Complete output from command /media/hd/SAVEfolder/SAVE/COMP/backtrack-linux/programming/pythonstuff/python-binance/python-binance/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-lgn7ecfx/TA-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-lzp5676l --python-tag cp37:
  /tmp/pip-install-lgn7ecfx/TA-Lib/setup.py:71: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
    warnings.warn('Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.')
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
```

```
  Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
  Running setup.py clean for TA-Lib
Failed to build TA-Lib
Installing collected packages: numpy, TA-Lib
  Running setup.py install for TA-Lib ... error
    Complete output from command /media/hd/SAVEfolder/SAVE/COMP/backtrack-linux/programming/pythonstuff/python-binance/python-binance/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-lgn7ecfx/TA-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-kf43df8h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /media/hd/SAVEfolder/SAVE/COMP/backtrack-linux/programming/pythonstuff/python-binance/python-binance/include/site/python3.7/TA-Lib:
    /tmp/pip-install-lgn7ecfx/TA-Lib/setup.py:71: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
      warnings.warn('Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.')
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    running build_ext
    building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/media/hd/SAVEfolder/SAVE/COMP/backtrack-linux/programming/pythonstuff/python-binance/python-binance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/media/hd/SAVEfolder/SAVE/COMP/backtrack-linux/programming/pythonstuff/python-binance/python-binance/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib/_ta_lib.o
    talib/_ta_lib.c:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/media/hd/SAVEfolder/SAVE/COMP/backtrack-linux/programming/pythonstuff/python-binance/python-binance/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-lgn7ecfx/TA-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-kf43df8h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /media/hd/SAVEfolder/SAVE/COMP/backtrack-linux/programming/pythonstuff/python-binance/python-binance/include/site/python3.7/TA-Lib" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-lgn7ecfx/TA-Lib/
```

1. what steps were done wrong attempting to install TA-Lib ?
2. is trying to install TA-Lib on an external HD causing the problem?

   - is there a way to isolate or sandbox TA-Lib install to one specific venv ?  To prevent conflict with other server and venv projects that have packages with complex dependencies...

- all other python and javascript programs seem to work within the venv
- can not 'fix' a million problems then clone, i will need to rebuild with correct (minimized) steps.  procedure to purpose build the server is a requirement i may not get around....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+invalid+command+bdist_wheel

Comment: yeah thanks.....The documentation isn't overly clear on this,.......  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26664184