# Why am I unable to install bpy via pip?

Tags: python, pip, manjaro, bpy

I'm trying to install `bpy` using `pip`, but I get the following:

```
pip install bpy
```

Output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting bpy
  Using cached bpy-0.0.0a0.tar.gz (19 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4w20jpx9/bpy_b62f07d1f8f946ce93c92ccd56a2fc60/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4w20jpx9/bpy_b62f07d1f8f946ce93c92ccd56a2fc60/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-67myzkf8
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4w20jpx9/bpy_b62f07d1f8f946ce93c92ccd56a2fc60/
    Complete output (45 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-neva89hz/svn_c1ad3cd7f91e47ec9b39d2ea30379414/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-neva89hz/svn_c1ad3cd7f91e47ec9b39d2ea30379414/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ygbk6314
           cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-neva89hz/svn_c1ad3cd7f91e47ec9b39d2ea30379414/
      Complete output (6 lines):
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help

      error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for svn
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 75, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpxv1t2_3h', '--quiet', 'svn']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-4w20jpx9/bpy_b62f07d1f8f946ce93c92ccd56a2fc60/setup.py", line 288, in <module>
        setup(name='bpy',
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 686, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 766, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1051, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1063, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 745, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 77, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpxv1t2_3h', '--quiet', 'svn']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26664184/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+invalid+command+bdist_wheel

Answer (score 0):

I just testing the installation on Python 3.9 for Windows 64 bits and Python 3.8 64 for Linux and it made the same error. But I found the solution. The problem is that version of Python, I tried to install bpy on the new Python version 3.7.3 for Windows 64 bits over a virtual machine and it works well.

The specifications about packages tell the version *requires* Python >=3.7, <3.8, so I think that is the problem.

https://pypi.org/project/bpy/

I attached the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66309425/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.